# Why am i getting a unknown value in console while running a for loop with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

Running the following code in the console:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let j = i;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(j);
    }, 0)
}
```

results in some strange behavior. When I run it once, I see something like:

[image]

What is that number at the top?

```
9 // what is this????
0
1
2
3
4
```

The next time I run it, it's different:

```
13 // what is this????
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: That's the return value of `setTimeout()`. In browsers, the handle is a positive integer that can be passed to `clearTimeout()` before the callback is scheduled to execute if you want to cancel it.

Comment: Its return value of `setTimeout` function to be stored and used in case `clearTimeout` is needed.

Comment: Thanks, I first thought it's returning some stack size.

Comment: Relevant part from the spec (wrt duplicate): https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console will log the result of the final expression that was evaluated. This is why, for example, typing in

```
'foo' + 'bar'
```

results in `'foobar'` being logged.

Here, the final expression evaluated (synchronously) is the `setTimeout`, and `setTimeout` returns an integer indicating the ID of the timeout (which can be used with `clearTimeout` later). `setInterval` works the same way. So the number you're seeing is that timeout ID. (it sounds like `setTimeout` was called 12 times previously on that load of the page)

Comment: It's not "just" the final expression (if that was the case, `var foo = 1` would log `1`), it's the "result" of the `for` loop.